# How to determine what sender agent php mail() function uses?

Tags: php, email, dns

My mail() php function sends email but its delivrability is very low.

My server is DEBIAN and I did not make the server installation.

the bounce address does not fit the domain name accoring to :
https://www.mail-tester.com/web-OPQmPm

> You may want to publish a DNS record (MX type) for the domain name
>   fox-main.bay30.ovh or use a different bounce email address.

My php.ini config is:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
```

My question is: what does the mail() php function in my case (postfix ? qmail ?...) and how to fix that ?

The recieved email is:

```
Received: by mail-tester.com (Postfix, from userid 500) id AF3D7A017A;
    Sun, 23 Oct 2016 14:52:39 +0200 (CEST)
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.1 (2015-04-28) on mail-tester.com
X-Spam-Level: **
X-Spam-Status: No/2.2/5.0
X-Spam-Test-Scores: HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS=0.001,
    HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_16=1.048,HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_06=0.001,HTML_MESSAGE=0.001,
    MIME_HTML_ONLY=1.105,SPF_HELO_PASS=-0.001,SPF_PASS=-0.001,
    T_RP_MATCHES_RCVD=-0.01,T_TVD_MIME_EPI=0.01
X-Spam-Last-External-IP: 91.121.157.162
X-Spam-Last-External-HELO: fox-main.bay30.ovh
X-Spam-Last-External-rDNS: fox-main.bay30.ovh
X-Spam-Date-of-Scan: Sun, 23 Oct 2016 14:52:39 +0200
X-Spam-Report: * -0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS SPF: HELO matches SPF record    * -0.0
 T_RP_MATCHES_RCVD Envelope sender domain matches handover relay    *     
 domain *  0.0 HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS From and EnvelopeFrom 2nd level
 mail   *      domains are different    * -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF
 record *  0.0 HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_06 BODY: HTML has a low ratio of text to
 image area *  1.0 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_16 BODY: HTML: images with 1200-1600
 bytes of words *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message  *  0.0
 T_TVD_MIME_EPI BODY: No description available. *  1.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY:
 Message only has text/html MIME parts
Received-SPF: Pass (sender SPF authorized) identity=mailfrom;
 client-ip=91.121.157.162; helo=fox-main.bay30.ovh;
 envelope-from=root@fox-main.bay30.ovh; receiver=web-opqmpm@mail-tester.com
DMARC-Filter: OpenDMARC Filter v1.3.1 mail-tester.com 46E079FF4E
Authentication-Results: mail-tester.com; dmarc=none
 header.from=fox-poker.com
Received: from fox-main.bay30.ovh (fox-main.bay30.ovh [91.121.157.162]) (using TLSv1.2
    with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)) (No client certificate requested)
    by mail-tester.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 46E079FF4E
    for <web-OPQmPm@mail-tester.com>; Sun, 23 Oct 2016 14:52:38 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from fox-main.bay30.ovh (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by fox-main.bay30.ovh (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4) with ESMTP id u9NCqceQ021366
    for <web-OPQmPm@mail-tester.com>; Sun, 23 Oct 2016 14:52:38 +0200
Received: (from root@localhost) by fox-main.bay30.ovh (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit)
    id u9NCqcrX021365;  Sun, 23 Oct 2016 14:52:38 +0200
Message-Id: <201610231252.u9NCqcrX021365@fox-main.bay30.ovh>
To: web-OPQmPm@mail-tester.com
Subject: Votre compte Fox-Poker, testEMail.php
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:email.php
Date: Sun, 23 Oct 2016 14:52:38 +0200
MIME-version: 1.0
From: contact@fox-poker.com
Return-Path: root@fox-main.bay30.ovh
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=_24cc77109e4a921619d8d5058adc7bd8_

Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
```

**Where does it take fox-main.bay30.ovh from ? (there is no such info in my email script !)**

Comment: Well, how could anybody tell? Do you have postfix? qmail? or something else? running?

Comment: I am running DEBIAN. I have no idea if this is postfix or maill or... I did not install the server.

Comment: Send yourself an email, and examine the headers (if it gets to you).

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157880/how-can-i-see-settings-of-the-email-server#comment467021_158646

Comment: This is off-topic / too broad either way. We can't guess your server setup, other than tell you that exim is Debians default, though your headers indicate qmail. And your mail body does in fact look spammy, as mail-tester already told you. Set a bounce address, or use a mail class and external MTA service. At this stage you'll be unable to diagnose anything.